# Laravel Atomic Locks

Tags: php, laravel, locking

I want to use an atomic lock on a specific method in my controller. I tried implementing it and it works but not the way I expected it to.

I want the users to only submit a single request after every 3 seconds.

This is my code:

```
Cache::lock('withdrawFunds'.Auth::id(), 3)
    ->get(function () use ($request) {
        // transaction code here
    });
```

The problem I am facing is that it is locking all the users when one user submits a request.

What I want to do is lock it only to the user who submits the request.

Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: what cache driver are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminGakami I'm using file driver